# Geometry of the discriminant locus of a morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a flat and  proper morphism between two smooth algebraic complex varieties. The fibres $X_y$ are projective varieties of the same dimension $d$.  The discriminant locus of $f$ is classically defined as:

$$\Delta(f):=\{y\in Y\colon X_y \text{ is singular} \}$$

> What do we know about the basic geometric properties of $\Delta(f)$?
> Is $\Delta(f)$ a subvariety of $Y$? What is its dimension?

I only know that if $Y$ is a curve, then $\Delta(f)$ is a finite set of points, i.e. the support of a divisor of $Y$.

Comment: $\Delta(f)$ is the image of the singular locus of $f$ (since $f$ is flat) which is closed, so is closed (since $f$ is proper). I think there’s a purity theorem somewhere (aka it has codimension one), but I’m not sure.